# Google tells me that http://mydomain.de.whoisbucket.com/ is not indexed

Tags: google-search-console

I got a report from Google Search console (sc-noreply@google.com):

```
Page indexing issues detected in http://sprechcomputer.de/

To the owner of http://sprechcomputer.de/:

Search Console has identified that your site is affected by 1 Page indexing issue(s). The following issues were found on your site. We recommend that you fix these issues when possible to enable the best experience and coverage in Google Search.

Top issues

    Page with redirect

Fix Page indexing issues
```

When I open search console, it says that 4 days ago, my URL was not indexed anymore.

However, I did not change anything.

It offers "INSPECT URL" and "TEST ROBOTS.TXT BLOCKING".

I click "TEST ROBOTS.TXT BLOCKING", and it tells me that I don't have a robots.txt
I click "INSPECT URL", and it shows this:

```
Referring page
http://sprechcomputer.de.whoisbucket.com/
http://www.whoisbucket.com/view/sprechcomputer.de
```

This is the only anomaly that I can see.

These are not my domains. Is this a bug in Search Console?

What is the problem here?

Also, none of my pages are indexed, according to this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I suspect Google is right. Have you looked the developer tools on your browser? It will show you the redirectiobs in the network tab.

Comment: Indeed, http://sprechcomputer.de/ is being redirected to https://sprechcomputer.de/ - so Google is right not to index the HTTP version of the page.   When I google sprechcomputer.de I do get the HTTPS version of your page, so your page is still in Googles index.